# implementing DFS or recursion and printing the traversed path in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml, depth-first-search

Creating absolute path from XML.

I have created a xml

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element("root1")
child1 = etree.SubElement(root, "child1")
child2 = etree.SubElement(root, "child2")
child21 = etree.SubElement(child2, "child21")
child201 = etree.SubElement(child21, "child221")
child3 = etree.SubElement(root, "child3")
print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

and now i have to print the traversed path like

```
/root1/child1
/root1/child2
```

util child has no more child

So far i have came a solution

```
xpathlist = []

if len(root):
    print(len(root))
    for child in root:
        print(child)
        xpath_1 = "/" + root.tag + "/" + child.tag
        xpathlist.append("".join(xpath_1.split()))
        if len(child):
            for minichild in child:
                print(minichild)
                xpath_1 = "/" + root.tag + "/" + child.tag + "/" + minichild.tag
                xpathlist.append("".join(xpath_1.split()))

for xx in xpathlist:
    print(xx)
```

which gives a following out put

```
/root1/child1
/root1/child2
/root1/child2/child21
/root1/child3
```

but as you see there is one path missing

```
/root1/child2/child21/child221
```

because it is in much deeper depth that my code can not handle and further more depth can be created.

Need a solution which can work with N number of depths and print the traversed path.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify this a lot by using lxml's [`getpath()`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#generating-xpath-expressions) method.

This is input.xml:

```
<root1>
  <child1/>
  <child2>
    <child21>
      <child221/>
    </child21>
  </child2>
  <child3/>
</root1>
```

Here is how you can generate an absolute XPath expression for each element in the XML document:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

for elem in tree.iter():
    print(tree.getpath(elem))
```

Output:

```
/root1
/root1/child1
/root1/child2
/root1/child2/child21
/root1/child2/child21/child221
/root1/child3
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but could you made necessary changes to my code also, it would help me building my concepts. thanks